# SQL Server backup overwrite increases in size

Tags: sql-server, backup, disk-space-utilization, sql-server-2016

I have a small database, that backs up to around 3.5mb.

If I overwrite the backup `Tasks -> Backup -> Type: Full -> Backup to disk` it increases in size each time around 3.5mb.

If I delete the existing backup, then follow the above process it's back to it's 3.5mb size again.  I only noticed because I backup my development DB to Dropbox and it got up to 100mb in size.

Is this a bug?  If not, what's going on?

Comment: is there any options to overwrite (init) the backup?

Comment: Are you doing incremental backups after the full or a full backup each time? The increments might be seeing the entire database as changed if you have some process that is changing the archive bits.

Comment: Ah, that's it!  In media options there's an 'overwrite all existing backup sets' which does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Script to do the backup and overwrite.

It's more easy than screen.

backup database NOME_BASE
to disk = 'c:\CAMINHO\BASE.bak'
WITH  INIT , STATS = 5